# Removing everything up to B after skipping N lines from A in Notepad++ (in a loop)

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I have lines starting with `2008`. Can I remove 6th and 7th lines matching colors but leave these with the surnames? So, this

```
...
    2008
    12
    17
    1229529342
    Mary
    Red
    Green
    Jackson

    2008
    9
    21
    1229529697
    Susan
    Orange
    White
    Wellington
...
```

can turn into this

```
...
    2008
    12
    17
    1229529342
    Mary
    Jackson

    2008
    9
    21
    1229529697
    Susan
    Wellington
...
```

Comment: This isn't really a job for regex, it's a job for a macro running in Notepad++ (if such a thing were possible).  This would be easy to do in any programming language such as Java or Python.

Comment: I'm not really into setting up environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(2008\R(?:.+\R){4}).+\R.+\R`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

DON'T check `. matches newline`

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start capture group #1
  2008\R        : 2008 followed by any kind of line break
  (?:           : start non capture group
    .+\R        : any character but newline, one or more times, followed by newline
  ){4}          : repeat group 4 times      
)               : end group 1
.+\R            : any character but newline, one or more times, followed by newline
.+\R            : any character but newline, one or more times, followed by newline
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1        : group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
...
    2008
    12
    17
    1229529342
    Mary
    Jackson

    2008
    9
    21
    1229529697
    Susan
    Wellington
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`2008[\n\r](?:.*[\n\r]){4}(.*[\n\r].*)`

The color lines are in capture group 1.

Explanation:

`2008[\n\r]         match 2008 and a line break
(?:.*[\n\r]){4}    non-capture group: find 4 occurrences of anything followed by linebreak
(.*[\n\r].*)       capture two lines`